# What is the correct way to deploy two different angular projects on netlify using the same custom domain?

Tags: angular, github, netlify

**Problem Summary:**

I have two separate angular projects:

1. My portfolio website
2. My personal project named "Agency"

I have successfully deployed these two projects on Netlify.

Then, I set up a custom domain for my portfolio website.

The URL for these projects are as follows:

1. Portfolio website (www.snsakib.com)
2. "Agency" website (https://project-agency.netlify.com)

I'm now trying to change the "Agency" website's URL as follows:

"www.snsakib.com/projects/agency/live-demo"

**Background & what I've already tried:**

Both projects are created with Angular 8.

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48604843/how-to-host-multiple-github-repos-using-the-same-custom-domain-on-netlify) & [this question](https://community.netlify.com/t/common-issue-can-i-deploy-multiple-repositories-in-a-single-site/179) are somewhat close to my problem.

I've successfully implemented the techniques provided by the above questions into a normal HTML,CSS & JS project. But when I try to implement this same technique to an Angular project the browser renders a blank page.

I've created a `_redirects` file in my portfolio website's repo & added the following rules:

```
# Redirects rules for showing project live demos
/projects/agency/live-demo https://project-agency.netlify.com 200!

# Redirects rules for single page application
/* /index.html 200
```

**Expected Result:**

While visiting "www.snsakib.com/projects/agency/live-demo" link the browser should render the website but it renders a blank white page.

If I visit the Netlify provided URL (https://project-agency.netlify.com) then the website renders properly.

Comment: I'm not sure but, the issue could be the redirects on the `https://project-agency.netlify.com/` site. Proxy rewrites and routing is a pain to deal with. Since it is a static demo, I would just make it a subdomain of the main domain with an explanation of the project on the project page `/projects/agency` with a link to the demo `agency-demo.snsakib.com`. This way you still get the rebuilds on the demo and the added marketing page.

Comment: What I understood from your answer that you are proposing me to configure [Branch Subdomains](https://www.netlify.com/docs/custom-domains/#branch-subdomains). Then I've to host all of my projects into a single repo but I'm trying not to do this. Because it's difficult to maintain all of my projects.

Comment: I'm not suggesting a branch subdomain, but a new site with the domain as a subdomain and a CNAME entry in DNS pointing to the Netlify site domain (your-new-site.netlify.com)

Comment: Ok. Now I get your proposal. 
It's a nice workaround indeed!
But I still want to implement the specific URL mentioned in the question.